# Creating AWS Security Group for a range of ports in Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

I want to create the following AWS security group in Terraform, using Hashi Corp Language. In this configuration the second ingress rule contains the range of ports, but such a syntax is not supported by Terraform.

In current implementation Terraform treats port's range as the math expression and computes the difference which gives the negative value. If I close the port range in parenthesis it fails because it requires number format.

What is the appropriate way to create ingress rule for a large range of ports?

```
  resource "aws_security_group" "sg_nx" {
  name   = "sg_nx"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  ingress {
    from_port   = 4000
    to_port     = 4000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 4011-4999
    to_port     = 4011-4999
    protocol    = "udp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Using list does not work either. I know Terraform allows dynamicly generated resources, how to implement it in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules.html they support port range. The way to do it with terraform is:

`from_port = 4011` and `to_port = 4999`

See also the terraform docs:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#from_port

Comment: Thanks, I have found the answer myself already. No examples of actual range of ports assignments in Internet, so I was wandering a lot.